# How to configure MySQL with Django

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

Am trying to use MySQL with Django 2.0, I have installed it using "pip install mysqlclient"  and it installed successfully. What do i need to do next?

Answer (score 2):

In `settings.py` you'll need:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'user_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'user_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
```

You'll need to create the db and user and grant permissions within MySQL.

You'll also need to ensure you have MySQL setup and running.

Comment: thank you, I finally got it to work and migrated successfully, but it gave a warning regarding strict mood, Please what is that all about

Comment: Please share the warning - I don't know off hand